# Can you draw images in an arc on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

You can draw arcs and you can draw images on a canvas using javascript, but is there anyway to do both? that is, is there anyway to draw an image as the arc instead of a solid line?

If not, is there a seperate way to arc an image?

I tried doing a pixel-by-pixel transformation of the image along the points of an arc, but it ended up being very slow and looking pretty poor since I can't directly get pixel data from javascript (or can you? I didnt see a way) so for each pixel, I needed to calculate the point along the arc, draw the current image pixel, refetch it, draw the image data to the calculated point, then clear that point on the canvas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried setting the strokeStyle to a CanvasPattern based on an image? It looks like you could do something like this (assuming `img` is an HTMLImageElement that you want to draw from and `ctx` is a CanvasRenderingContext2D):

```
var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "repeat");
ctx.strokeStyle = pattern;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(123, 408, 80, 0, 1.5*Math.PI, false);
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: Doing it like this will not as good as you can get it. Its better to use ctx.translate to the arcs upper left corner (so that the patterns origo will exist at that point) and then draw the arc around that. The same goes for sizes, you might have to scale the pattern to get the desired size with ctx.scale()

Comment: Hm interesting, I had no idea you could use an image for the stroke. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @Megatron I didn't know either until I looked it up in [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/Overview.html#conformance-requirements). I'm assuming you already have that reference in your back pocket, but as a reminder, it usually has the answers to this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use this html to create arc : -

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="250"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var x = canvas.width / 2;
  var y = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 75;
  var startAngle = .8 * Math.PI;
  var endAngle = 2.2 * Math.PI;
  var counterClockwise = false;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
  context.lineWidth = 30;

  // line color
  context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  context.stroke();
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var x = canvas.width / 2;
  var y = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 75;
  var startAngle = 8 * Math.PI;
  var endAngle =2.3 * Math.PI;
  var counterClockwise = false;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
  context.lineWidth = 30;

  // line color
  context.strokeStyle = 'red';
  context.stroke();
</script>
```