# How to insert an image into a canvas arc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

here is my script, I am trying to insert an image into the arc canvas to replace only the black part but no solution :/ it is th first time I post on Stack, hope you can help me.
A fiddle to see the script too : http://jsfiddle.net/a1u6jmfj/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="250"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var x = canvas.width / 2;
      var y = canvas.height / 2;
      var radius = 50;
      var startAngle = 1.1 * Math.PI;
      var endAngle = 1 * Math.PI;
      var counterClockwise = false;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
      context.lineWidth = 100;

      // line color
      context.strokeStyle = 'black';
      context.stroke();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't understand: do you want your image to replace (only) the black area in the canvas, or do you want the image the fill the white area inside the circle in the canvas ?

Comment: yes you're right only the black part

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951647/can-you-draw-images-in-an-arc-on-a-canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing)

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = /*image url*/;
image.onload = function() {
    context.save();
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    context.restore();
};
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/a1u6jmfj/1/)